# How to hide class first and show only on hover in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have following toggling script:

```
  $('.edit_bg').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
      $(this).addClass('edit_bg');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
      $(this).removeClass('edit_bg');
    }
  });
```

But this works after i first hover that div.

How should I remove all `.edit_bg` classes from divs on start and be able to show them on hover?

Comment: It would be better to use two classes e.g.: `.edit` and `edit-hover`.

Comment: @dfsq you mean first hide all ``.edit`` and then add class ``edit-hover``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the on function just do `removeClass`.

```
$('.edit_bg').on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).addClass('edit_bg');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).removeClass('edit_bg');
    }
}).removeClass('edit_bg');
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you are trying to achieve using Javascript/jQuery, but you can achieve it simply using css:

```
.edit_bg
{
    background-color: blue;
}

.edit_bg:hover
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Look, ma! No javascript! http://jsfiddle.net/adrianonantua/rv9ht/